# Check if the 4x4 grid has 2 adjacent numbers(up or down) equal to a certain number

Tags: python, list

```
The user has to enter a 4x4 grid of numbers as follows:
[[2,1024,8,8],
 [4,1024,16,32],
 [2,32,64,128],
 [8,256,2,2]]
```

Next, the user is asked for a number such as for this particular example I choose 2048.

Now the code needs to check if the sum of any 2 adjacent boxes(Up or Down) have the addition as the given number, in this case, 2048, if yes, the box is correct else false.
Print the result.

The code must include sublists and not dictionaries or tuples etc.

Well, I am fairly new to python and got this question online.
I tried my head around this but to no avail. All I have created till now is a sublist to take input and tried doing it individually one by one checking but it takes too long.

- **Edit 1:** I tried a sample code which is the long method, but getting an error as list indices must be integers or slices, not tuples. Hopefully would also like to shorten the code.

***Here's the code***

```
a=[[2,1024,8,8],
   [4,1024,16,32],
   [2,32,64,128],
   [8,256,2,2]]

def winning(a):
 for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        if (i==0):
            if(j==0):
                if a[i,j]+a[(i+1),j]==2048:
                    True
            if(j==3):
                if a[i,j]+a[i+1,j]==2048:
                    True
            if a[i,j]+a[i,j-1]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i+1,j]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i,j+1]==2048:
                True
        if(i==1 or i==2):
            if(j==0):
                if a[i,j]+a[i,j+1]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i-1,j]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i+1,j]==2048:
                    True
            if(j==3):
                if a[i,j]+a[i-1,j]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i+1,j]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i,j-1]==2048:
                    True
            if a[i,j]+a[i,j-1]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i,j+1]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i-1,j]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i+1,j]==2048:
                True
        if(i==3):
             if(j==0):
                if a[i,j]+a[i-1,j]==2048:
                    True
             if(j==3):
                if a[i,j]+a[i-1,j]==2048:
                    True
             if a[i,j]+a[i,j-1]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i-1,j]==2048 or a[i,j]+a[i,j+1]==2048:
                True
 return false

assert winning(a)
```

Comment: *The code must* - sounds good, show the appropriate efforts, post your code

Comment: Ok, added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to split code in more functions of what you need. Furthermore, you can also make variables for not hard-coding values into your code (unless this matrix 4x4 is the only way you intend to do this operation).

First, we find how many rows there are in this matrix and if the length of every row is equal to a constant value (and not different between them);
then we define two functions:

- `sum_up_down`, given a position (index of row and index of column), give us a tuple holding the element in such position, the sum with its upper value and the sum with its lower value;
- `find_number` just loop over the matrix, find every tuple possible and at the first match (`number in result`, where `number` is your choice, example 2048, and `result` the tuple holding the three values).

We then print the matrix and loop, finding every time the number specified by user.

If you don't need/want the element to be found (just sum up and down) just edit the return of `sum_up_down` and delete `element`

```
my_list = [
    [2,1024,8,8],
    [4,1024,16,32],
    [2,32,64,128],
    [8,256,2,2]
]

number_rows = len(my_list)
if number_rows == 0:
    raise ValueError("Cannot play with an empty matrix!")
length_row = len(my_list[0])

# verify that every row length is equal to the first found
for row in range(number_rows):
    assert len(my_list[row]) == length_row

def sum_up_down(row, col):
    """Returns a tuple holding the element found at (row,col),
    the sum with its upper value and the sum with its lower value
    in the matrix (only if the element is not boundary)."""
    elem = my_list[row][col]
    up_sum = elem
    down_sum = elem

    if row != 0:  # can sum up
        up_sum += my_list[row-1][col]

    if row != number_rows - 1:  # can sum down
        down_sum += my_list[row+1][col]

    return elem, up_sum, down_sum

def find_number(number):
    """Find the choosen number in my_list applying sum_up_down
    row*col times. If found, returns True, False otherwise."""
    for row in range(number_rows):
        for col in range(length_row):
            result = sum_up_down(row, col)
            if number in result:
                print(
                    "{} was found as elem / sum up / sum down of {} ({},{})".format(
                        number, result[0], row, col
                    )
                )
                return True
    print("{} not found!".format(number))
    return False

# show matrix
for row in my_list:
    print(row)

while True:
    number = int(input("Insert the number you want to find: "))
    find_number(number)
```

Comment: well thank you for the answer, it helped me a lot. And also learned something new in the process.